# Animated plot using matplotlib with gtk

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, pygtk, python-multiprocessing

I did the following example code just to test how to integrate an animated matplotlib plot with pygtk. However, I get some unexpected behaviors when I run it.

First, when I run my program and click on the button (referred to as button1 in the code), there is another external blank window which shows up and the animated plot starts only after closing this window.

Secondly, when I click on the button many times, it seems that there is more animations which are created on top of each other (which gives the impression that the animated plot speeds up). I have tried to call animation.FuncAnimation inside a thread (as you can see in the comment at end of the function on_button1_clicked), but the problem still the same.

Thirdly, is it a good practice to call **animation.FuncAnimation** in a thread to allow the user to use the other functions of the gui ? Or should I rather create a thread inside the method **animate** (I guess this will create too many threads quickly) ? I am not sure how to proceed.

Here is my code:

```
import gtk
from random import random
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import FigureCanvasGTK as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkcairo import FigureCanvasGTKCairo as FigureCanvas

class HelloWorld:
    def __init__(self):
        interface = gtk.Builder()
        interface.add_from_file('interface.glade')

        self.dialog1 = interface.get_object("dialog1")
        self.label1 = interface.get_object("label1")
        self.entry1 = interface.get_object("entry1")
        self.button1 = interface.get_object("button1")
        self.hbox1 = interface.get_object("hbox1")

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

        self.X = [random() for x in range(10)]
        self.Y = [random() for x in range(10)]
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.X, self.Y)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        # self.hbox1.add(self.canvas)
        self.hbox1.pack_start(self.canvas)

        interface.connect_signals(self)
        self.dialog1.show_all()

    def gtk_widget_destroy(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        name = self.entry1.get_text()
        self.label1.set_text("Hello " + name)

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=self.init, interval=25, blit=True)
        '''
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        async_result = pool.apply_async(animation.FuncAnimation, args=(self.fig, self.animate, np.arange(1, 200)), kwds={'init_func':self.init, 'interval':25, 'blit':True} )
        self.ani = async_result.get()
        '''
        plt.show()

    def animate(self, i):
        # Read XX and YY from a file or whateve
        XX = [random() for x in range(10)] # just as an example
        YY = [random() for x in range(10)] # just as an example

        self.line.set_xdata( XX )
        self.line.set_ydata( YY )

        return self.line,

    def init(self):
        self.line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(self.X, mask=True))
        return self.line,

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HelloWorld()
    gtk.main()
```